# Не отображается в инспекторе переменные с public и SerializeField. Что делать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image]
[image]

Может это из за того, что внутри класса Unity не понимает что надо отобразить.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вставьте код текстом. Перепечатывать код с картинки для создания ответа - нет спасибо.

Comment: Поля класс `PieceData` сериализуемые, а поле `chessPrices` нет, потому что сам по себе тип не `[Serializable]`. Плюс инспектор не отображает многомерные массивы насколько я помню.

Comment: @Yaroslav и что это значит?

Comment: Про вставить код текстом игнор чтоли?

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно. У вас поля написаны во внутреннем классе `PieceData`, а не в `PieceMovement`

Comment: Нет, даже так не работает

Comment: .......так - как?

Comment: так как это как?

Comment: ну, передразнивание, не приближает тебя к цели

Comment: Не стоит отвечать на неоформленный вопрос.

Comment: @aepot это где-то в правилах прописано?)

Comment: Это позволяет авторам вопроса забивать и не доводить их оформление до ума. А так, может быть где-то и прописано, но я не помню. Кстати, этот ответ больше похож на комментарий, как мне кажется. В нем не хватает объяснений, как автору исправить ситуацию или хотя-бы предложений вариантов решения проблемы, куда копать или что почитать. Обозначен только факт - причина проблемы без решения.

Comment: @aepot в ответе вполне всё написано. Если автор не имбецил, то сопоставить свой код и ответ вполне можно. И ответы не обязаны быть километровой простынёй, чтобы быть ответом................ *"позволяет авторам вопроса забивать и не доводить их оформление до ума. "* --- наличие ответа никак не мешает что-то доводить до ума. Можно авторам писать в комментариях под вопросам как следует поступать. А если автору пофиг - ему в любом случае будет пофиг

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я значит что-то не понимаю, зачем мы пишем ответы. Ну вам виднее.

Comment: @aepot зачем вы пишите километровые ответы? Я не знаю зачем  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯